# Histogram by matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

[image: Data Table]

I want to create the histogram to compare total system costs and total incentive approved.

```py
x = np.arange(7)

y1 = ['Total System Costs']
y2 = ['Total Incentive Approved']

bar_width = 0.3

tick_label = ['2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018']
 
plt.bar(x, y1, bar_width, color='salmon', label='Total System Costs')

plt.bar(x + bar_width, y2,bar_width, color='orchid', label='Total Incentive Approved')

plt.legend()

plt.xticks(x + bar_width / 2,tick_label)

plt.show()
```

What's wrong with my coding above?

[image: My result]

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK. The problem is that *matplotlib* does not know how to arrange the y-axis, because your data is not numeric. So it places the first "value" at 0 and the second above it (at 1). The result is that `y1 = ['Total System Costs']` shows a bar of zero height, which you can't observe.

If you call `ax.get_ylim()` on your axis (`plt.gca().get_ylim()` in your case as you don't open an axis handle explicitly), you'll note that it returns something like

> `(0.0, 1.05)`
> If `y1` now represents 0, it explains why you don't see something.

Even extending the limits of the y-axis (lets say `plt.gca().set_ylim((-1,1.05))`) won't help, because the height of the bar is still zero (starting at 0 to 0...).

To illustrate the theory, I added a single line with a new y-value to your code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(7)

y1 = ['Total System Costs']
y2 = ['Total Incentive Approved']

bar_width = 0.3
plt.bar(0,'zero',bar_width) # <<<<< additional bar plot
plt.bar(x, y1,bar_width, color='salmon', label='Total System Costs')
plt.bar(x + bar_width, y2,bar_width, color='orchid', label='Total Incentive Approved')

plt.legend()
# set tick labels
tick_label = ['2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018']
plt.xticks(x + bar_width / 2,tick_label)

plt.show()
```

[image: bars]